# Java anonymous class (implementing an interface) callback is null when passed to another function

Tags: java, interface, callback, jsonobjectrequest, geocoder

I'm attempting to implement a callback for Android Java JsonObjectRequests. I've found dozens of posts showing code that is nearly verbatim. My problem is that the `callback` is null. See the two inline comments.

```java
public interface JsonObjectCallbackInterface {
    void onSuccess(JSONObject result);
}
```

```java
class DispatchBuddyBase {
    //...

    public void addGmapMarker(String inAddress) {
        final String address = DBB.prepareAddress(inAddress);
        DatabaseReference ref = DBB.getTopPathRef("/geocodedAddresses");

        ref.orderByChild("address")
                .equalTo(address)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.i(TAG, address+" stored: "+dataSnapshot.exists());
                if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    DBB.getLatLng(
                           "17 River Rd Meriden CT 06451",
                            new JsonObjectCallbackInterface() {
                         //      ^--- why is this passing a **null?**

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "got a json body:"+response.toString());
                            addGmapMarker(response);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```java
public class DispatchesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult> {
    //...

    public void getLatLng(final String address,
                          final JsonObjectCallbackInterface callback) {
        // why does this get a **null** callback? -------------^

        Log.e(TAG, "callback is: "+callback);
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
                + address;

        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.e(TAG,"Response: " + response.toString());
                        DatabaseReference ref = getTopPathRef("/geocodedAddresses").push();

                        Map<String, Object> u = new HashMap<>();
                        u.put("address", address);
                        u.put("geocoded", response.toString());

                        ref.updateChildren(u, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError,
                                                   DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                                if (databaseError != null) {
                                    Log.e(TAG,"Geocoded address could not be saved "
                                            + databaseError.getMessage());
                                } else {
                                    Log.e(TAG,"Geocoded address saved successfully.");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        Log.e(TAG, "callback2 is: "+callback);
                        callback.onSuccess(response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });

        DBVolley.getInstance(context)
                .addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
    }
}
```

To be clear, I did once note that `callback` was not null *just once* when I was testing. Repeat runs have not produced a non-null callback since then. I'm only 8 days into Java, so please pardon if I've done something naive.

The `DispatchBuddyBase` singleton is instanced in the main activity just once, and `DBVolley` likewise. All additional references obtain the same via `DispatchBuddyBase.getInstance()`. I haven't had any problems with anonymous classes elsewhere.

The Volley code is bare bones and fires off requests just fine, the JsonObjectRequest successfully gets everything I expect from Google. Everything else is working swell except for this callback.

What do I need to fix to correctly pass this callback?

Comment: `new Whatever()` is *never* null: your problem must be elsewhere

Comment: ahh, if you can't fix your problem, post it on stack*, you'll figure it out quickly and thump your head against the wall... i'll mark my post solved shortly

Comment: Flagging for deletion, as the whole thing is a misunderstanding (see OP answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, marking this solved. Occam's razor. I unintentionally hit ctrl-z too much and uncommented in another section of code that was calling with a literal null parameter for the callback.

The above code works perfectly.